# How to get current timestamp in Android without it updating like a clock

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I'm trying to get a timestamp in android, this is my code;

```
public String getTimestamp() {
    String timestamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    return timestamp;
}
```

When I create a variable to display the timestamp.

Ex) String timestamp = getTimestamp();

This should save the current timestamp as a string. However when I print this string 'timestamp', it continues updating in real time like a clock. I just want the current timestamp. I don't have it in a for loop or anything, where it could be updating.

Here is where it's being printed out:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idView);

    GeLoBeacon beacon = beacons.get(position);

    if (!beaconsFound.contains(Integer.toString(beacon.getBeaconId()))) {
        beaconsFound.add(Integer.toString(beacon.getBeaconId()));
    }
    String times = getTimestamp();
    nameView.setText(times);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: if you called getTimestamp() once, returned String cant' be updated, Please show code where you print this string

Comment: @Max77 I added the code where it is being printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public String getTimestamp() {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
      return sdf.format(new Date());
}
```

Change the format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") and get your date in that particular format!

Comment: That's just a different way of formatting the timestamp, it doesn't solve the problem with the updating timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Your method getView() called on each item of adapter and therefore different time set on each item. Set timestamp as field variable in adapter before calling method listView.setAdapter()

Answer (score 0):

define timeStamp as a field variable then use setTimeStamp(){ //to assign current time}   and getimeStamp() { return timeStamp;) to read the timeStamp value.