# How do I stop SimpleDateFormat from updating the time

Tags: java, android

I saw that this was asked once at [How to get current timestamp in Android without it updating like a clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168695/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-android-without-it-updating-like-a-clock), but it wasn't marked as answered and I don't understand the few suggestions that were given.

Anyway, I'm beyond new to Java and was following a tutorial on making a simple todo app (https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Todo-App-Tutorial) and I decided to try to add a timestamp to each list item. I got as far as that it adds the current time, but its not static. The time keeps updating anytime I try and add a new item or if I close and reopen the app. I can't figure out/find the answer anywhere.

This is what I'm getting:
[image: This is what I get]

This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

Here's the code.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> TodoAdapter;
private ListView lvItems;

private void readItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
    try {
        items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

private void writeItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    readItems();
    TodoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, items);
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    lvItems.setAdapter(TodoAdapter);
    // Setup remove listener method call
    setupListViewListener();
}

// Attaches a long click listener to the listview
// Removes item on long press
private void setupListViewListener() {
    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                    // Remove the item within array at position
                    items.remove(pos);
                    // Refresh the adapter
                    TodoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    writeItems();
                    // Return true consumes the long click event (marks it handled)
                    return true;
                }

            });
}

public void onAddItem(View v) {
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    TodoAdapter.add(itemText); // Add items to new Adapter type
    etNewItem.setText("");
    writeItems();
}
}
```

TodoAdapter.java

```
public class TodoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Todo> {
    public TodoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Todo> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Todo item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
    }

    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

    text1.setText(item.itemText);
    text2.setText(item.getCreationTimeString());
    text2.setTextSize(10);

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Todo.java

```
public class Todo {
    String itemText;
    private Date creationTime;

    public Todo(String text) {
        this.itemText = text;
        this.creationTime = new Date();
    }

    public String getCreationTimeString() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(creationTime);
    }
}
```

Any help provided would be extremely appreciated. Also please keep in mind that I have literally almost no understanding of what I'm doing. :)

Comment: `new Date()` always returns the current date/time at the time it is called.

Comment: `new Date()` always uses current system time.

Comment: You need to save task creation date within the file

Comment: Robert, how would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The time keeps updating anytime I try and add a new item

Right, that is because the Adapter is recalling `new Date()`, which will *always* get the current time that the View is created for an Adapter item.

It would appear that you want items to be associated with a time at which they are created. If that is the case, then you can make a class

```
public class Todo {
   String itemText;
   private Date creationTime;

   public Todo(String text) {
      this.itemText = text;
      this.creationTime = new Date();
   }

   public String getCreationTimeString() {
       return new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(creationTime);
   }
}
```

Then, you should probably [make an `ArrayAdapter<Todo>`](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter) to display these items and display something like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Todo item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
    }

    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

    text1.setText(item.itemText);
    text2.setText(item.getCreationTimeString());
    text2.setTextSize(10);

    return convertView;
}
```

And update the add method

```
public void onAddItem(View v) {
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(new Todo(itemText)); // Add items to new Adapter type
    etNewItem.setText("");
    writeItems();
}
```

Comment: When I do that it now uses the time from the first time the code is run. So now all the items are showing up as 4:48pm.

Comment: Sorry I meant static for each item. Specifically I want a static stamp of when I add each item. So item shows a time of 4:54pm, then when I add a second item two minutes later it should show that item with a time of 4:56. Is clearer?

Comment: @Bradbains Yup. Updated answer, and you can follow along with [Making a Custom ArrayAdapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter) for the parts that I skipped.

Comment: I've tried to implement what you've given me but I must have done it incorrectly–as previously stated I have zero Java skills–as I keep getting errors. I've updated the code here and marked the errors I'm getting.

Comment: My bad with the Todo class constructor. Not sure what the other errors are. If you are unfamiliar with how to debug some Java errors, though, I'd recommend taking a step away from app development until you have a good understanding of core Java

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. Each `public class` definition has to be in its own file. You can't have multiple `public class`-es at the same "level" of one file. You also implemented the Adapter incorrectly. Please follow that tutorial I linked again (in full)

Comment: Hi @cricket_007. Sorry to bother you but I was hoping you'd be kind enough to look at my code one more time. You mentioned prior that I implemented the custom Adapter incorrectly, but I followed the structure of the source you linked me to, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: @Bradbains You need to replace all occurrences of `ArrayAdapter<String>` with your new `TodoAdapter` class. And all `ArrayList<String>` with `ArrayList<Todo>`. Make sense?

Comment: it totally does. Thanks again for helping out a stranger. I really appreciate it.